# PhpMailer Attachments (Web-Hosted)

Tags: php, phpmailer

As a relative newbie to PHP I've been very impressed with the ease of implementation of the functionalities behind PHPMailer 5.2.0 so far for use on the contact me page of my website which is still under construction. However, I have a small problem and have been searching all of SO, the PhpMailer GitHub, and the rest of the web for a solution for the last few hours and I am completely stumped to be honest as none of the answers seem to quite fit what problem I am experiencing.

What I want on my website's contact form page is to allow users to send me an email using my form including their full name, email address, any attachments they want to send, and their message followed by my email signature.

The current situation is this; when a user fills out the contact form on the contact.html page the results are posted to the email.php form and everything is sent to my email as it is supposed to, followed by sending an auto-response message to the senders email address. However, I am not receiving the attachments in the emails, but i can receive both the initial email and the auto-response if I use another email account I can access, and they are not being uploaded to the uploads folder in my website directory.

I think, from what I have read so far, that I have incorrectly set up 2 things and am also unable to find a php.ini file in my website directory.

The first thing is the structure of my websites public_html folder which contains the following related files and folders; contact.html, email.php, class.phpmailer.php, class.smtp.php, PHPMailerAutoload.php, and a folder called uploads with the privileges set to enable read and write by all user types.

The second thing I assume is wrong is in the following extract of PHP code, taken from the included example in the PHPMailer Git download (the example is not wrong, just my use of it), which I should probably edit to point to the uploads folder instead of "sys_get_temp_dir()":

```
//Attach multiple files one by one
for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    //The line below may be looking for the wrong directory?
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    } else {

    }
}
```

The current form is coded similarly to below, having been trimmed of all unnecessary styling for easy reading, in the file "contact.html":

```
<form method="post" action="email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
        <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple">
    </div>

    <div>
        <textarea rows="20" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message Text..." required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="recaptchaContainer">            
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*" data-callback="enableBtn">
    </div>   

    <div>
        <button id="sendMsgBtn" type="submit">
            Send Message
        </button>
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the email.php code it posts to, as defined in the form tag:

```
<?php

// When we unzipped PHPMailer, it unzipped to
// public_html/PHPMailer_5.2.0
require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// $name, $email, and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$file = 'images/test.jpg' ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

/*Attach multiple files one by one
for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    } else {

    }
}*/

$emailsig = 'Email signature...' ;

// set mailer to use SMTP
//$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication                
$mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS";                 
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.live.com';      
$mail->Port       = '587';

// Email address & Password:
$mail->Username = "************@**********.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "******************"; // SMTP password

// $email is the user's email address the specified
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("****************@***************.com", "***********");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from " . $name . " via your website!";

$mail->AddAttachment( $file, 'test.jpg' );

// $message is the user's message they typed in
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$mail->Body    = nl2br($message) . $emailsig;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}  else {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
    $mail->From = "*********@*********.com";
    $mail->FromName = "******** - Auto-Response";
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
    $mail->Subject = "Auto-reply message from ********!";
    $message = 'Some auto-reply message text here...';
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($message) . $emailsig;

    $mail->send();

    echo "Message has been sent successfully!";
}

?>
```

I have a feeling it is due to a problem with what I have done (or not done) on my web server combined with not pointing to the upload folder in my directory and maybe even not pulling the files across to my php file initially? What I would like to know really is a step-by-step set of instructions for sorting out my code and setting this up on my web server if anyone can help?

I very much appreciate the fact that my question will probably have WAY too much detail and is probably an easy fix for someone who is an expert on this sort of thing, I just wanted you to have all the information at your disposal to make working this one out a bit easier.

Comment: `$mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS"` should be `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"`, but that won't be the problem. You don't need an uploads folder if you're sending files submitted along with the form. I suggest you check your paths and that the uploaded files are actually present and correct - for example do calls to `addAttachment` actually a) happen and b) succeed?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that @Synchro. I changed it from "TLS" to "tls". I also nuked the multiple files section temporarily and replaced it with `$file = 'images/test.jpg';` , `$mail->AddAttachment( $file, 'test.jpg' );` and `$mail->ClearAttachments();`. It sent my email with attachment stored in my directory to my email, and the auto-response to the initial senders' email without the attachment. Now I know that works I'll have a go in the morning at getting it to pull the upload across from the file input and then I'll post an update on progress. For now, I'll edit my code in the initial question!

Comment: @Synchro I am currently working on solving the problem but I have run into a bit of a larger issue than this initial question details. I am using AJAX to submit the email through to email.php to avoid refreshing the page or loading the email.php directly. I am receiving the email text content but not the attachment. So, is it actually possible to attach a file to an email using data pulled using AJAX to populate $_FILES with the data or is there another way of doing this I am not realising?

Comment: It is possible, but that's a different question. Don't try to fix both things at once - get each part working separately, then you'll know where your problem is.

Comment: @Synchro Ok, I really am kinda stumped on the uploading files as attachments without having to upload them to my directory. I seem to be able to attach files directly from my directory though direct calls in the php file, as evidenced in the changes I made, I just still have no idea what I'm doing wrong to be honest. I know it's something to do with my file paths...